# How to run RegAsm /codebase with an InstallScript project?

Tags: com, installshield, regasm, installscript

I tried this question on the InstallShield forum and it hasn't gotten any love.  My company has an InstallScript project (non-MSI), and we need to run RegAsm /codebase on one of our DLLs.  I found some tutorials online for doing this, but they don't seem to apply to our project type.  That is, the options I need simply do not exist in the UI.  That includes both suggestions here (https://www.iwasdot.com/installshield-execute-a-batch-script/) as well as anything involving custom actions (as I interpret from the docs that custom actions do not apply to InstallScript projects).  How can I accomplish this with InstallScript?  I am using InstallShield 2013 and I know extremely little about it.

Comment: Any reason to not switch to Windows Installer project types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used InstallScript projects in almost 20 years but I imaging you'd write an InstallScript function to call LaunchAppAndWait to invoke Regasm.

If I recall correctly, InstallScript project types have events like After File Copy that you can use to put the code into.

Answer (score 0):

Christopher Painter is correct.  I came to the same conclusion and was able to get this to work.  If it helps anyone in the future, here's more specifically what I did:

I went to the "Behavior and Logic" folder of the "Installation Designer" tab and selected "InstallScript".  Then on the right-hand pane I selected the feature my DLL is associated with and then selected the "Installed" event handler.  The following script registered my DLL for COM interop:

`LaunchApplication("C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/RegAsm.exe",
"../path/to/my.dll /codebase", "",
SW_HIDE, 0, LAAW_OPTION_NOWAIT);`

And then I did something similar for the "Uninstalled" event handler:

`LaunchApplication("C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/RegAsm.exe",
"/unregister ../path/to/my.dll", "",
SW_HIDE, 0, LAAW_OPTION_NOWAIT);`